what is the time-zone for the "day"?
I've had my consecutive visits count reset several times now, after logging in during my afternoon instead of my morning.  What is the time-zone that is used for determining when the day begins and ends, and can something be done to cater for different time-zones?
(and it would be nice to get my visit count back, but that's not a question...)


What is the time-zone that is used for determining when the day begins
  and ends

UTC

can something be done to cater for different time-zones?

This has been suggested before on Meta Stack Overflow and has been status-declined

I see, so the consecutive visits becomes a race condition in that case.

@peterferrie Depends. I log in at an almost fixed time every day, so I dont have any issues with whatever time zone is used.

good for you, but I don't have that luxury, so I am very much affected by it.

You could post another [tag:feature-request] on [metase]. It was declined by Jeff Atwood in '11, who has now left Stack Exchange, so it might have a chance.
